# Tableau - Divide values from 2 dates

Tags: tableau-api, date-range, calculation

I need help making a division with a relative date range.

`For example:
   Date Range: 01-01-2015 & 20-01-2015
   Divison: 1.209,812 / 1.207,810 = 1,0016575`

[image: Example of Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of LOD calcs and a Context Filter.

Select Add to Context on your relative range date filter.

[image]

Create Level of Detail calcs to isolate the min and max dates based on your filter

```
{max([Order Date])}
```

and

```
{min([Order Date])}
```

Create min and max values based on your measures. I'm using the Superstore data set in this example. The calculation states if the date equals the max date, return the Sales value. Repeat for min values.

```
if [Order Date] = [max date] then [Sales] end
```

You should have something like this:

[image]

Now just create a division between the max and min. You'll need to remove the date from the view for the calculation to render.

```
sum([max value]) / sum([min value])
```

[image]

See attached sample workbook if needed. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ed15pwhihmjkdv/181227%20stack%20question.twbx?dl=0